# RegEx: How to find all instance of a collocation?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a script in python to find word collocations in a text. A word collocation is a pair of words that co-occur often in various texts. For example in the collocation "lemon zest", the words lemon and zest co-occur often and thus it is a collocation. Now I want to use `re.findall` to find all occurences of a given collocation. Unlike "lemon zest", there are some collocations that wouldn't be next to each other in texts. For example, in the phrase "kind of funny", because "of" is stop word, it would be already removed. So given the collocation "kind funny", a program has to return "kind of funny" as output.
Can anybody tell me how to do this? I should mention that I require a scalable approcah as I am dealing with gigabytes of text

Edit1:

```
inputCollocation = "kind funny"
Document1 = "This film is kind of funny"
Document2 = "It is kind of funny"
Document3 = "That film is funny"


ExpectedOutput: Document1, Document2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you kindly show your attempts ? Also it's kind of unclear to me. Do you give a certain input (two words) and try to search for them in your text or do you want to dynamically detect those words. Also, if `lemon zest` occurs only once in your text, should it match/return true ?

Comment: Presumably you have some kind of database of collocations. A sample from that, a short sample input file, and the expected output given those inputs might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I give a certain input (of two words) as well as a document to search those words in. Yes, for any given input of two words it should match to even a single instance of it. Also, I have to mention that each document is only 10 words in length.

Comment: @user823743 [Here](http://regex101.com/r/cH3hQ5)'s a start `kind\s*\S*\s*funny`, don't forget the `i` modifier. `\s*` means match a whitespace zero or more times and `\S*` means match anything not a whitespace zero or more times. Now you only need to think about constructing the regex dynamically while looping

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string comparison:

```
inputCollocation = "kind funny"
documents = dict(
    Document1 = "This film kind funny",
    Document2 = "It kind funny",
    Document3 = "That film funny",
)

def remove_stopwords(text):
    ...

matching = [ 
    document for (document, text) in documents.iteritems() 
    if inputCollocation in remove_stopwords(text.lower()) 
]
print 'ExpectedOutput:', ', '.join(matching)
```

You could also consider using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html) which has tools for finding collocations.